# Could the robots.txt file be overridden by another robots.txt in sub folder?

Tags: seo, robots.txt

I know `robots.txt` is supposed to go in the root directory. But, could it be overridden by another `robots.txt` inside a sub directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It is only valid to have one robots.txt file which is paced inside the root web directory of the website. Other robots.txt files are invalid and will be ignored (and never even looked for as crawlers only look in the root directory and never elsewhere. You can't even tell them to look elsewhere).

Comment: Thanks for reviewing my question. Yes, I suspected it and I wanted to be sure it was this way. I believe you are right. Isn't there any link to a source where to verify/confirm this?

Comment: The [official robots.txt website](http://www.robotstxt.org/) is about as good as it gets.

Comment: If you have subdomains, each of the must have a robots.txt if not, the  bots can crawl them.